# Get FCM Token in a background service

Tags: java, android, service, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am starting a background service in which I want to get my FCM token, so I create a getFcmtoken function for that. Unfortunately the other function I am passing on addOnCompleteListener doesn't get called, however when I call my getFcmToken in my MainActivity outside the service it works just fine.

Here's my getFcmToken function:

```java
  public static void getFcmToken(Context context) {
    FirebaseMessaging
      .getInstance()
      .getToken()
      .addOnCompleteListener(
        new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(Task<String> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
              Log.w(
                "ERROR",
                "Fetching FCM registration token failed",
                task.getException()
              );
              return;
            }
            String token = task.getResult(); // it doesn't get to here!
          }
        }
      );
  }
```

I have debugged this through notifications so I am confident in what I am saying.

Why does this function works in MainActivity, but not it my service? How can I fix that?

Comment: why not use local storage to save fcm token in Mainactivity and fetch it when need it. or use static variable (not recommended). or you really want to fetch it in service? why?

Comment: That's a good idea! I could save my FCM token with my JWT when the user loges in, but the FCM tokens have an experation time, don't they? This is a problem for my app since it runs mainly bacground/foreground services.

Comment: no it does not expire unless user reinstall the app.

Comment: Than you for the assistance - this solution is suitable, but why doesn't it work in the service? Now I am just curious